# string output all substring including non-adjacent

Tags: python, string, algorithm

For example the string 'abc' outputs all substrings, which are `'a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc','abc'`
Importantly, `'ac'` is a non-adjacent substring.

```
lines = input()
res = [lines[i: j] for i in range(len(lines)) for j in range(i + 1, len(lines) + 1)]
```

which outputs all adjacent substrings. How can I modify this function to include non-adjacent substring? Thank you

Comment: This is exactly function `powerset` in the [**itertools recipes**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: As for vocabulary, there is a relatively well-established convention that "substrings" are contiguous, and "subsequences" need not be: [Difference : subsequences and substrings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237097/difference-subsequences-and-substrings)

Comment: Do you know that there are no repeated letters in your string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
from itertools import combinations

s = 'abc'
for i in range(1, len(s)):
    for item in combinations('abc', i):
        print(''.join(item))
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
ab
ac
bc
abc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `combinations` from `itertools`:

```
# s = 'abc'
>>> [''.join(j) for i in range(1, len(s)+1) for j in combinations(s, i)]

['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'bc', 'abc']
```